# MySQL unique static ID

Tags: mysql, installation, uniqueidentifier

I need to get an unique static ID that is not changeable by the users, and if the user copies the database to another server this static ID is different.

## Background

My company wants to sell our app and allow for the end user to control the administration of the database.  At the same time we do not want someone to pay for one license and then install the app on 100 different database (as an extreme example).

I thought `server_id` was is needed. Then, I found out that it can be configured by the end user. Therefore, this is no good.

thanks for the help!

Comment: ID of what? MySQL installation? Database? Machine?

Comment: It is a non-trivial problem.  Once you think you have solved it, a customer complains that he had to replace his motherboard, and your app no longer works.  (Because it was depending on, say, some unique id found on every motherboard, such as the MAC-address.)

Comment: @mustaccio machine would be best

Comment: @RickJames I understand that is an issue going into this.  Re-issuing a code not a concern, and if we are constantly re-issuing them we have an issue :P

Comment: Unless your license costs more than one person-year worth of development time, you'll spend more money maintaining your copy protection scheme than you can earn from additional licenses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try [server_uuid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid)

Other have addressed using it

- [Beware of MySQL 5.6 server UUID when cloning slaves](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/01/21/beware-mysql-5-6-server-uuid-cloning-slaves/)
- [Resolving Error: master and slave have equal MySQL server UUIDs](http://www.chriscalender.com/resolving-error-master-and-slave-have-equal-mysql-server-uuids/)

Some may resort to copying the `auto.cnf` to another server, which would then have the same generated [server_uuid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid). You would have to code something that would scan a network on port 3306, sniff out the `auto.cnf` file, and check the UUID inside the file.

You could probably make the following requirements and coalesce them

- Require the presence of the `auto.cnf`
- Use [Unique Identifier from Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144812/generate-consistent-machine-unique-id) and imbed it yourself into `auto.cnf` as [server_uuid](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options.html#sysvar_server_uuid)
- Match the UUID in `auto.cnf` with the machine as well as mysqld
- Somehow broadcast that UUID so that your app can detect the presence of more than one occurrence of that UUID in the network

Doing these things may require taking the UUID your app generated and writing that UUID back into the installation software. That way, subsequent installations could compare the UUID of the machine with the now updated UUID from the first installation. Any match would have to deny installation thereafter.

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but how do retrieve the server_uuid as select @@server_uuid; does not work

Comment: Please try `select @@global.server_uuid;`. If you do not get a result, then I assume you must be running MySQL 5.5 or prior. server_uuid was introduced in MySQL 5.6.

Comment: Yeah that is the problem, 5.5 is the version

Comment: I will look at upgrading

Comment: No problem. Look at the post http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144812/generate-consistent-machine-unique-id. Generate your own UUID and just compare it on installation. I don't know if you can store in `auto.cnf` but you can store it somewhere

Comment: I don't see how this helps.  The server_uuid seems like it would be pretty simple to change, too... it's still stored in a file, just not in the normal config file.